# Something seems to be stuck in memory

Tags: python, memory

I have a program that loops over a list and then performs a function on the list.  The result that is getting returned from the function is different depending on whether I loop over several observations versus just one.  For example when I put in the 10th observation by itself, I get one result but when I put in 9 and 10 and loop over them I get a different answer for 10.  The only thing I can come up with is that there is some variable in storage that is leftover from performing the function on 9 that is leading to something different for 10.  Here's the code for the loop:

```
for i, k in enumerate(Compobs):
    print i+1, ' of ', len(Compobs)
    print Compobs[i]
    Compobs[i] = Filing(k[0],k[1])
```

`Compobs` is just a list like this:

```
[['355300', '19990531'],[...],...]
```

The function `Filing` is from another .py file that I import. It defines a new class, `Filing()` and performs a bunch of functions on each observation and ultimately returns some output.  I'm fairly new to python so I'm at a bit of a loss here.  I could post the Filing.py code, but that's over 1,000 lines of code.

Here's the Filing class and the **init**.

```
class Filing(object):
    cik =''
    datadate=''
    potentialpaths=[]
    potential_files=[]
    filingPath =''
    filingType=''
    reportPeriod=''
    filingText=''
    current_folder=''
    compData=pd.Series()
    potentialtablenumbers=[]
    tables=[]
    statementOfCashFlows=''
    parsedstatementOfCashFlows=[]
    denomination=''
    cashFlowDictionary ={}
    CFdataDictionary=OrderedDict()
    CFsectionindex=pd.Series()
    cfDataSeries=pd.Series()
    cfMapping=pd.DataFrame()
    compCFSeries=pd.Series()
    cftablenumber=''
    CompleteCF=pd.DataFrame()


    def __init__(self,cik,datadate):
        self.cik=cik
        self.datadate=datadate
        self.pydate=date(int(datadate[0:4]),int(datadate[4:6]),int(datadate[6:8]))
        self.findpathstofiling()
        self.selectfiling()
        self.extractFilingType()
        self.extractFilingText()
        self.getCompData()
        self.findPotentialStatementOfCashFlows()
        self.findStatementOfCashFlows()
        self.cleanUpCashFlowTable()
        self.createCashFlowDictionary()
        self.extractCFdataDictionary()
        self.createCFdataSeries()
        self.identifySections()
        self.createMapping()
        self.findOthers()
```

Shouldn't all the variables in the Filing.py get cleared out of memory each time it is called?  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You at least need to post the `__init__` method of Filing. This is almost certainly either the mutable default argument issue, or the use of class attributes rather than instance attributes; without seeing some of the code there's no way to tell.

Comment: I've updated it to include it.  Thanks.

Comment: Yup. It's most likely the mutable **class** members (not instance). When @DanielRoseman said to post the code of `__init__`, he meant all of it, including all the functions it calls. Otherwise it's useless until we see where the fields are being set.

Comment: What are mutable class member?  Could you just point me in the right direction as to what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the lists, dicts, and other objects defined at the top level of `Filing` have only one copy.  Even if you explicitly assign them to an instance, that copy is shared (and if you don't explicitly assign them, they're inherited).  The point is that if you modify them in one instance, you modify them in all instances.

If you want each instance to have its own copy, then get rid of the top-level assignments altogether, and instead assign new instances of the objects in `__init__`.

In other words, don't do this:

```
class Foo(object):
    x = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = x
```

Instead, do this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = []
```

Then each instance will have its own, unshared copy of `x`.

Comment: This seems very helpful.  I've changed the code as follows, but now I'm getting the error: AttributeError: 'Filing' object has no attribute 'self'

    class Filing(object): 
     def __init__(self,cik,datadate):
      self.potentialpaths=[]
       self.self.potential_files=[]
      self.filingPath =''
      ....

Comment: Sorry.  Had a stupid error.  Ignore the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your class data members as class attributes, not object attributes. They are like static data member of a C++ or Java class.

To fix this, you need to not define them above the `__init__` method, but instead, define them in the `__init__` method. For example, instead of

```
tables = []
```

above `__init__` you should have:

```
self.tables = []
```

in `__init__`